# Uncomment config line with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to uncomment specific lines in a php config, which is looking like that:

```
; the current environment.
; Default Value: clean env
;env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
;env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
;env[TMP] = /tmp
;env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
;env[TEMP] = /tmp

[...]

;php_flag[display_errors] = off
;php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
;php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M
```

I'm trying to uncomment the following lines with sed (removing the ; at the beginning):

Comment: there are more lines beginning with ;env that I DONT want to uncomment.

```
;env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
;env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
;env[TMP] = /tmp
;env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
;env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

several SED attempts of my own failed:
1st try:

```
sed -i "s/;env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME/env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME/g" /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

2nd try with escaping the var:

```
sed -i "s/;env[HOSTNAME] = \/$HOSTNAME\//env[HOSTNAME] = \/$HOSTNAME\//g" /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Even serval attempts with .* failed.

In the result I want this blog to look like this (uncommented)

```
env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: you need to escape all instances of the `$` character as well as the `[` and `]` that show up in the `search` pattern (optional for the `replacement` pattern), eg: `sed "s/;env\[HOSTNAME\] = \$HOSTNAME/env[HOSTNAME] = \$HOSTNAME/g"`; from a performance perspective you're probably looking at something like `awk` if you need to process a number of lines ...

Comment: assuming you're only going to have a single entry for `;env[HOSTNAME]` you could shorten the code to `sed "s/;env\[HOSTNAME\]/env[HOSTNAME]/g"`

Comment: Thanks! That reply was a help! I knew that I have to escape / and $, but that I also have to escape [] was kinda new to me. SED is tricky sometimes :) Now my question is solved, thanks!